# Concrete5 create select box via form helper with array from db

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, helper, concrete5

I'm trying to make a select box, using the build in helper, with array from the db on a single page.
I used in the single page controller:

```
$comp = $db->getAll('SELECT id, name FROM table', array());
$this->set('companies', $comp);
```

and in the single page:

```
$cmp = array();
foreach($companies as $company){
$cmp[] = "'".$company['id']."' => '".$company['name']."'";
}; 
$cmp = implode(", ", $cmp); 
echo $form->select('companyID', array($cmp), '1');
```

and the result is this:
`<select id="companyID" name="companyID" ccm-passed-value="1" class="form-control" pmbx_context="B49783CE-698A-47B4-8895-3D930C747D42"><option value="0">'1' =&gt; 'Bucuc', '2' =&gt; 'Neocrest'</option></select>`

I mean instead of new option for each array it give me a single value and past the whole array at once.
I would like to get:
`<select id="companyID" name="companyID" >
<option value="1">Bucuc</option>
<option value="2">Neocrest</option>
</select>`

Anyone can point me where is the problem?
By the way I'm working on a Concrete 5.7.5.8 install.
Thanks, Xaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Created 2 arrays, one for keys and one for values and then combined them.
Here is the final code:

```
$key = array();
$value = array();
foreach($companies as $company){
    $key[] = $company['id'];         
    $value[] = $company['name'];
}; 
$c = array_combine($key, $value);
echo $form->select('companyID', $c, '1');
```